# In terminal of CorePlus (tinyCore) linux, running openJdk java gives me syntax error “unterminated quoted string”

Tags: linux, terminal, java

These are the steps I took

- installed tiny core linux on an old laptop
- opened the terminal and set to have root permissions via "sudo su"
- navigated to the specific jdk/bin folder (openJdk-16 was extracted from a tar.gz)
- used the "ls" command, verifying I am in the correct folder with
  "java"
- "chmod +x java" to make "java" executable
- "./java" to run java

At this point, I would have expected to see a
java console with the print out of java command line options,
instead, it gives this error

```
./java: line 5: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

I also tried "chmod +x ./java" followed by "./java -h", and got the same error message.

very new to linux, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

The laptop I am using is much older than I realized...it is a 32 bit system!  I was trying to run 64 bit java.  I did "uname -a" and it said i686, which means 32 bit, so I found an old 32 bit build of java 8 and it ran just fine.